# iOS 7 mysterious crash

Tags: ios, crash, ios7, crash-reports

We have an iOS game on the AppStore and some users are reporting problems since they've upgraded to iOS 7. We've updated the game to work on iOS 7 and have tested it extensively  with several devices. However, we have some users reporting crashes, sometimes in the exact same devices we've tested and re tested the game on. 
The crash log, after being symbolicated, reads as follows:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreGraphics                    0x2d4ec9ca CGColorSpaceGetModel + 10
1   QuartzCore                      0x2f893842 CA_CGColorGetRGBComponents + 30
2   QuartzCore                      0x2f95a142 -[NSObject(CAAnimatableValue) CA_distanceToValue:] + 86
3   UIKit                           0x2fe10c72 _UIViewLayerAnimationCanBeConsideredFinished + 250
4   UIKit                           0x2fe10ae2 __22-[UIWindow sendEvent:]_block_invoke + 10
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d3c4022 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 50
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2d3bda0a -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 218
7   UIKit                           0x2fc1b556 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 522
8   UIKit                           0x2fbf0a20 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
9   UIKit                           0x2fbef21c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7092
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2d446188 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2d445656 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2d443e4a __CFRunLoopRun + 618
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2d3aece2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2d3aeac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x320cf27e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x2fc50a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  MyGame                          0x00104382 main (main.m:13)
18  MyGame                          0x0010435c ___lldb_unnamed_function455$$MyGame + 36
```

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to check color animation in your view. Maybe you perform somewhere animation from [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:] to [UIColor whiteColor]? or [UIColor blackColor]?

Comment: Another possible variant that you have background task in your app. Some UI code may be executed in background and causes crash.

Comment: Also some comletion block can be executed and may change properties of view that's already not in the view hierarchy. But it's just try to guess - posted log is not enough to fix crash - let QA team detect what sequence of user actions causes crash exactly, it will help you to find out the reason

Comment: @PetroKorienev I don't have any background task in my game and even though I do have some animations on layers that change the fill color those seem to be correctly implemented. Thanks

Comment: @PetroKorienev QA team? That would be me too ;)

Comment: Crash log says that for some CGColor RGB components can't be get - this means this color is not RGB color. I want to say on more time. [UIColor whiteColor] is NOT RGB, same for black. Color with hue, saturation, value isn't also RGB. So i suggest to check one more time these possible issue. Sorry if i just have written obvious thing to you) Just i think it's probably the issue.

Comment: @PetroKorienev I see what you mean know, I'll check for those, but I really don't think that's the problem since we don't perform animations going to or from black. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this is the problem

> 5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d3c4022 __53-**[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]**_block_invoke + 50

I was using the block enumerator for staggered animations and it caused my app to crash, with the message"

> [UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance

I'm using ARC and a static method call so not sure why this is happening.

However, changing this loop to a foreach style loop fixed the issue. The block inside a block worked fine in iOS5 and 6 but gave strange results and then crashes in iOS7

Comment: I'm not using a block enumerator to iterate through any set of animations so I'm quite sure this is not my problem. Thanks

Comment: Does `_block_invoke` mean that the crash happened within the block?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things missing from your crash report, mainly the exception (deallocated instance? missing selector?), however we can still deduce some things:

`[UIWindow sendEvent:]`

This is a call coming from event handling, probably a **touch** made by the user.

I guess the UIKit code then checks if the event can be delireved by checking whether there is some active animation `_UIViewLayerAnimationCanBeConsideredFinished`.

I am also guessing it's some animation in the window layer. Are you creating your own windows or adding views directly to `UIWindow`? Or maybe changing the root view controllers with an animation?

Anyway, go to try touching the screen during animations, always trying both the view the is appearing and the view that is dissappearing.

Comment: It is somehow related to two animations interacting when a user taps the screen twice in a short period. At the time of the crash I'm not modifying anything related to the UIWindow or the root view controller. As this was causing crashes on production I just had to remove one of the animations and that sorted the issue, but even knowing which animation was the culprit I wasn't able to figure out the problem. Both animations seemed to be configured properly and were working fine prior to iOS 7.

Comment: @EliBud Could you share more details about the animations?

Answer (score 0):

The enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock makes use of background threads. If one of these background threads does work on GUI objects (animations count in this of course) it will crash.

When the crash happens go to the left side in Xcode and select the debug navigator. You will most likely see a crash in a Thread x unequal Thread 1. Only Thread 1 which is the GUI thread is allowed to play with the GUI.

To solve your problem you have at least two options:

a) Put the animation GUI work you do inside a dispatch_async oder dispatch_sync block like

```
    …enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock … {

        // non GUI stuff    

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            // GUI work
            // non GUI stuff is also okay here
        });

        // non GUI stuff  

} // end of enumerateObjectsUsingBlock
```

b) Use fast enumeration instead of enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock and avoid background threads this way.

I guess iOS 7 uses more internal threading and maybe iOS 6 was not able to use background threads with these calls and thus did not cause a problem on 6 but on 7.

Have fun!

Comment: I'm not using enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock at all. Anyway I ended up having to remove the animation because I couldn't find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Your crash log contains "NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:" ;-)

Comment: I know it does, but it's inside CoreFundation code, not mine.

Comment: the log shows the error happens on thread0 though -- so while this is true I don't think this answer is valid